# Encoding Video in Java

Tags: java, video, video-encoding, mp4

I am trying to create a screen recorder type thing and I cannot figure out how to encode multiple BufferedImages into a watchable format like mp4. I would prefer pure Java code and I cannot use anything that the end user has to install before working. I can get all the audio and frames I just need to figure out how to make the video.

How to encode video with audio in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- JpegImagesToMovie (uses the core JMF - no natives) will convert groups of JPEG images to a Quicktime .MOV.
- JMF also has apps. for merging sound and audio.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an open source pure java H.264 codec from JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ). In order to compress a sequence of BufferedImages into an MP4 file use the class below:

```
public class SequenceEncoder {
    private SeekableByteChannel ch;
    private Picture toEncode;
    private RgbToYuv420 transform;
    private H264Encoder encoder;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> spsList;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> ppsList;
    private CompressedTrack outTrack;
    private ByteBuffer _out;
    private int frameNo;
    private MP4Muxer muxer;

    public SequenceEncoder(File out) throws IOException {
        this.ch = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(out);

        // Transform to convert between RGB and YUV
        transform = new RgbToYuv420(0, 0);

        // Muxer that will store the encoded frames
        muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

        // Add video track to muxer
        outTrack = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 25);

        // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold output frames
        _out = ByteBuffer.allocate(1920 * 1080 * 6);

        // Create an instance of encoder
        encoder = new H264Encoder();

        // Encoder extra data ( SPS, PPS ) to be stored in a special place of
        // MP4
        spsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        ppsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

    }

    public void encodeImage(BufferedImage bi) throws IOException {
        if (toEncode == null) {
            toEncode = Picture.create(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), ColorSpace.YUV420);
        }

        // Perform conversion
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            Arrays.fill(toEncode.getData()[i], 0);
        transform.transform(AWTUtil.fromBufferedImage(bi), toEncode);

        // Encode image into H.264 frame, the result is stored in '_out' buffer
        _out.clear();
        ByteBuffer result = encoder.encodeFrame(_out, toEncode);

        // Based on the frame above form correct MP4 packet
        spsList.clear();
        ppsList.clear();
        H264Utils.encodeMOVPacket(result, spsList, ppsList);

        // Add packet to video track
        outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(result, frameNo, 25, 1, frameNo, true, null, frameNo, 0));

        frameNo++;
    }

    public void finish() throws IOException {
        // Push saved SPS/PPS to a special storage in MP4
        outTrack.addSampleEntry(H264Utils.createMOVSampleEntry(spsList, ppsList));

        // Write MP4 header and finalize recording
        muxer.writeHeader();
        NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SequenceEncoder encoder = new SequenceEncoder(new File("video.mp4"));
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(String.format("img%08d.png", i)));
        encoder.encodeImage(bi);
    }
    encoder.finish();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately JCodec was significantly changed so your example does not compile anymore. Could you please edit your post and make it compatible with current Version?

Comment: i need the current version too, any tutorial to send me?

Comment: This seems to be the current way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41141827/671296