# How to encode images into a video file in Java through programming?

Tags: java, image, video-encoding, xuggler

I am trying to encode some images of same resolution into a video file using, For that I have tried:

**jCodec**

- [jcodec](http://jcodec.org/)..example [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220486/how-can-i-turn-a-series-of-images-into-a-video-using-jcodec)

  But it is very time consuming and not a proper tool to encode large number of images and it creates a quick time extension.

**FFMPEG**

- [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/)..example [description](http://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/)

  But ffmpeg only able to create video from image files. Images need to be create on physical system.

I have heard [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads) that its APIs can be used in java program to create video file but as its site seems broken. I am unable to try it.

Does anybody know how to encode images in java format into a video file Please help!

THanks in Advance !

Comment: and why don't you save your images to disk and create a video from them?

Comment: @JohnnyAW first it is time consuming,second, reduce unnecessary disk usage. third, I want to minimize external dependencies and cross-platform dependencies.

Comment: btw, I just looked on jcodec-site and found this example: Encode a sequence of images into MP4 file. Isn't that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @JohnnyAW sorry, I forget to tell that I have used  `jcodec` but it is very time consuming. it almost take 6 seconds to encode 60 images into a video of 2.5 seconds  on an Intel Ci5 processor System.

Comment: video-encoding IS time consuming, btw, why would you even bother? just let it run over night... nvm, I'm out, since you have working code and just looking for better codec

Comment: @JohnnyAW I am using it for real time using on a webapp.

Comment: Which format do you want the result in?

Comment: @stepanian  I want my video in `.mp4` or `.mov`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Xuggler](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler) is **deprecated**, use [Humble-Video](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video) instead. It already comes with some demo projects, including how to take screenshots and convert it to a video file: [RecordAndEncodeVideo.java](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video/blob/master/humble-video-demos/src/main/java/io/humble/video/demos/RecordAndEncodeVideo.java)

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2014, Art Clarke.  All rights reserved.
 * <p>
 * This file is part of Humble-Video.
 * <p>
 * Humble-Video is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * <p>
 * Humble-Video is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
 * <p>
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
 * along with Humble-Video.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *******************************************************************************/
package io.humble.video.demos;

import io.humble.video.*;
import io.humble.video.awt.MediaPictureConverter;
import io.humble.video.awt.MediaPictureConverterFactory;
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Records the contents of your computer screen to a media file for the passed in duration.
 * This is meant as a demonstration program to teach the use of the Humble API.
 * <p>
 * Concepts introduced:
 * </p>
 * <ul>
 * <li>Muxer: A {@link Muxer} object is a container you can write media data to.</li>
 * <li>Encoders: An {@link Encoder} object lets you convert {@link MediaAudio} or {@link MediaPicture} objects into {@link MediaPacket} objects
 * so they can be written to {@link Muxer} objects.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p>
 * To run from maven, do:
 * </p>
 * <pre>
 * mvn install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="io.humble.video.demos.RecordAndEncodeVideo" -Dexec.args="filename.mp4"
 * </pre>
 *
 * @author aclarke
 *
 */
public class RecordAndEncodeVideo
{
    /**
     * Records the screen
     */
    private static void recordScreen (String filename, String formatname, String codecname, int duration, int snapsPerSecond) throws AWTException, InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        /**
         * Set up the AWT infrastructure to take screenshots of the desktop.
         */
        final Robot robot = new Robot();
        final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        final Rectangle screenbounds = new Rectangle(toolkit.getScreenSize());

        final Rational framerate = Rational.make(1, snapsPerSecond);

        /** First we create a muxer using the passed in filename and formatname if given. */
        final Muxer muxer = Muxer.make(filename, null, formatname);

        /** Now, we need to decide what type of codec to use to encode video. Muxers
         * have limited sets of codecs they can use. We're going to pick the first one that
         * works, or if the user supplied a codec name, we're going to force-fit that
         * in instead.
         */
        final MuxerFormat format = muxer.getFormat();
        final Codec codec;
        if (codecname != null)
        {
            codec = Codec.findEncodingCodecByName(codecname);
        }
        else
        {
            codec = Codec.findEncodingCodec(format.getDefaultVideoCodecId());
        }

        /**
         * Now that we know what codec, we need to create an encoder
         */
        Encoder encoder = Encoder.make(codec);

        /**
         * Video encoders need to know at a minimum:
         *   width
         *   height
         *   pixel format
         * Some also need to know frame-rate (older codecs that had a fixed rate at which video files could
         * be written needed this). There are many other options you can set on an encoder, but we're
         * going to keep it simpler here.
         */
        encoder.setWidth(screenbounds.width);
        encoder.setHeight(screenbounds.height);
        // We are going to use 420P as the format because that's what most video formats these days use
        final PixelFormat.Type pixelformat = PixelFormat.Type.PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
        encoder.setPixelFormat(pixelformat);
        encoder.setTimeBase(framerate);

        /** An annoynace of some formats is that they need global (rather than per-stream) headers,
         * and in that case you have to tell the encoder. And since Encoders are decoupled from
         * Muxers, there is no easy way to know this beyond
         */
        if (format.getFlag(MuxerFormat.Flag.GLOBAL_HEADER))
        {
            encoder.setFlag(Encoder.Flag.FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER, true);
        }

        /** Open the encoder. */
        encoder.open(null, null);


        /** Add this stream to the muxer. */
        muxer.addNewStream(encoder);

        /** And open the muxer for business. */
        muxer.open(null, null);

        /** Next, we need to make sure we have the right MediaPicture format objects
         * to encode data with. Java (and most on-screen graphics programs) use some
         * variant of Red-Green-Blue image encoding (a.k.a. RGB or BGR). Most video
         * codecs use some variant of YCrCb formatting. So we're going to have to
         * convert. To do that, we'll introduce a MediaPictureConverter object later. object.
         */
        MediaPictureConverter converter = null;
        final MediaPicture picture = MediaPicture.make(encoder.getWidth(), encoder.getHeight(), pixelformat);
        picture.setTimeBase(framerate);

        /** Now begin our main loop of taking screen snaps.
         * We're going to encode and then write out any resulting packets. */
        final MediaPacket packet = MediaPacket.make();
        for (int i = 0; i < duration / framerate.getDouble(); i++)
        {
            /** Make the screen capture && convert image to TYPE_3BYTE_BGR */
            final BufferedImage screen = convertToType(robot.createScreenCapture(screenbounds), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

            /** This is LIKELY not in YUV420P format, so we're going to convert it using some handy utilities. */
            if (converter == null)
            {
                converter = MediaPictureConverterFactory.createConverter(screen, picture);
            }
            converter.toPicture(picture, screen, i);

            do
            {
                encoder.encode(packet, picture);
                if (packet.isComplete())
                {
                    muxer.write(packet, false);
                }
            } while (packet.isComplete());

            /** now we'll sleep until it's time to take the next snapshot. */
            Thread.sleep((long) (1000 * framerate.getDouble()));
        }

        /** Encoders, like decoders, sometimes cache pictures so it can do the right key-frame optimizations.
         * So, they need to be flushed as well. As with the decoders, the convention is to pass in a null
         * input until the output is not complete.
         */
        do
        {
            encoder.encode(packet, null);
            if (packet.isComplete())
            {
                muxer.write(packet, false);
            }
        } while (packet.isComplete());

        /** Finally, let's clean up after ourselves. */
        muxer.close();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException
    {
        final Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("h", "help", false, "displays help");
        options.addOption("v", "version", false, "version of this library");
        options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("format").withLongOpt("format").hasArg().
                withDescription("muxer format to use. If unspecified, we will guess from filename").create("f"));
        options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("codec")
                .withLongOpt("codec")
                .hasArg()
                .withDescription("codec to use when encoding video; If unspecified, we will guess from format")
                .create("c"));
        options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("duration")
                .withLongOpt("duration")
                .hasArg()
                .withDescription("number of seconds of screenshot to record; defaults to 10.")
                .create("d"));
        options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("snaps per second")
                .withLongOpt("snaps")
                .hasArg()
                .withDescription("number of pictures to take per second (i.e. the frame rate); defaults to 5")
                .create("s"));

        final CommandLineParser parser = new org.apache.commons.cli.BasicParser();
        try
        {
            final CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
            final String[] parsedArgs = cmd.getArgs();
            if (cmd.hasOption("version"))
            {
                // let's find what version of the library we're running
                final String version = io.humble.video_native.Version.getVersionInfo();
                System.out.println("Humble Version: " + version);
            }
            else if (cmd.hasOption("help") || parsedArgs.length != 1)
            {
                final HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
                formatter.printHelp(RecordAndEncodeVideo.class.getCanonicalName() + " <filename>", options);
            }
            else
            {
                /**
                 * Read in some option values and their defaults.
                 */
                final int duration = Integer.parseInt(cmd.getOptionValue("duration", "10"));
                if (duration <= 0)
                {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("duration must be > 0");
                }
                final int snaps = Integer.parseInt(cmd.getOptionValue("snaps", "5"));
                if (snaps <= 0)
                {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("snaps must be > 0");
                }
                final String codecname = cmd.getOptionValue("codec");
                final String formatname = cmd.getOptionValue("format");
                final String filename = cmd.getArgs()[0];

                recordScreen(filename, formatname, codecname, duration, snaps);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception parsing command line: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert a {@link BufferedImage} of any type, to {@link BufferedImage} of a
     * specified type. If the source image is the same type as the target type,
     * then original image is returned, otherwise new image of the correct type is
     * created and the content of the source image is copied into the new image.
     *
     * @param sourceImage
     *          the image to be converted
     * @param targetType
     *          the desired BufferedImage type
     *
     * @return a BufferedImage of the specifed target type.
     *
     * @see BufferedImage
     */
    public static BufferedImage convertToType (BufferedImage sourceImage, int targetType)
    {
        BufferedImage image;

        // if the source image is already the target type, return the source image

        if (sourceImage.getType() == targetType)
        {
            image = sourceImage;
        }

        // otherwise create a new image of the target type and draw the new
        // image

        else
        {
            image = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), targetType);
            image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
        }

        return image;
    }
}
```

Check other demos too : [humble-video-demos](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video/tree/master/humble-video-demos)

> I am using it for real time using on a webapp.

If you will gonna stream this in real time you will need a [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) server. You can either use big frameworks like [Red 5 Server](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server), [Wowza Streaming Engine](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?769-wowza-streaming-engine-product-articles) or you can built your own server using [Netty](http://netty.io/) which has a built in RTSP codec since version 3.2.

Comment: thanks ! yes, I am planning to use it in webapp. So after creating video on server-side. For real time streaming What should I do so that my client can  easily download the video.

Comment: I am creating Images in my program as `BufferedImage` object and I don't want to save them on server to avoid physical storage. Is it possible that I can directly use these `BufferedImage` object to encode them into video.

Comment: @Mavie "real time streaming" and "**downloading** video" are actually different things. If you want client to be able to just download created video take a look at this question [Implementing a simple file download servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/implementing-a-simple-file-download-servlet). If you want to live view a continuous video on a web site, i already listed some RTSP servers on the answer, look for their documents/examples.  [Some demos for Red5](https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples)

Comment: @Mavie about your second comment, example code already creates screenshots as `BufferedImage`'s in memory without saving them on disk. Only the video itself will written to the disk. If you want to create video on memory, i dont think that is possible with Humble-Video because `Muxer.make()` method expect a file name or url.

Comment: thanks , Can you tell me how to build [humble-video](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video) on windows as it does not provide any information for it. Have you used [humble-video](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video)

Comment: @Mavie No not really. I have used Xuggler before, actually i wondered what is wrong with Xuggler and found humble-video. I have only tested that sample code with 999 target fps option to see how fast it can actually produce a video and end up with a video around 200 fps. Since your actual concern about jCodec was speed I thought it is fast enough and decided to post it as an answer. You don't have to build for windows. Use maven, it already includes built artifacts.

Comment: @Mavie or you can use [Online Maven download tool](https://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php) which will let you download required jars from maven as a zip file.

Comment: thanks !, You said you have used in a realtime webapp. how many images you have used to create your video. Is there any parameters or Settings I need to do because in my case it is taking 23 seconds to convert 2000 `BufferedImages` of 1000x1000 pixels size in 25 FPS on a Intel Core i5 processor with 8 GB RAM. I don't think 23 seconds will be in realtime.

Comment: Have u ever combined two video using `humble-video`?

Answer (score 12):

Using command line, there are various ways to convert image to video. You can use those command in java for saving. You can get those commands from the following link:

1. [Using ffmpeg to convert a set of images into a video](http://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/)
2. [Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

### I am sharing a code snippet to solve the issue:

**code to save png image from HTML5 canvas**

```
Base64 decoder = new Base64();
byte[] pic = decoder.decodeBase64(request.getParameter("pic"));
String frameCount = request.getParameter("frame");
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(pic);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
String outdir = "output\\"+frameCount;
//Random rand = new Random();
File file = new File(outdir);
if(file.isFile()){
    if(file.delete()){
        File writefile = new File(outdir);
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", file);
    }
}
```

**Code for creating image from video**

```
String filePath = "D:\\temp\\some.mpg";
String outdir = "output";
File file = new File(outdir);
file.mkdirs();
Map<String, String> m = System.getenv();

/*
 * String command[] =
 * {"D:\\ffmpeg-win32-static\\bin\\ffmpeg","-i",filePath
 * ,"-r 30","-f","image2",outdir,"\\user%03d.jpg"};
 * 
 * ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command); pb.start();
 */
String commands = "D:\\ffmpeg-win32-static\\bin\\ffmpeg -i " + filePath
        + " -r 30  -f image2 " + outdir + "\\image%5d.png";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

**code for creating video from image**

```
String filePath = "output";
File fileP = new File(filePath);
String commands = "D:\\ffmpeg-win32-static\\bin\\ffmpeg -f image2 -i "
        + fileP + "\\image%5d.png " + fileP + "\\video.mp4";
System.out.println(commands);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
System.out.println(fileP.getAbsolutePath());
```

Credit goes to @[yashprit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420238/yashprit)

---

### Another approach for Android developers:

1. Create a temporary folder inside the Android.
2. Copy your images in the new folder
3. First, rename your pictures to follow a numerical sequence. For
   example, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg,... Then you may run:
4. Run this program programmetcally ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg
   /tmp/a.mpg To run this programmatically,

Use the following code:

```
void convertImg_to_vid()
{
    Process chperm;
    try {
        chperm=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
          DataOutputStream os = 
              new DataOutputStream(chperm.getOutputStream());

              os.writeBytes("ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg\n");
              os.flush();

              chperm.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Resource Link:

1. [Create a Video file from images using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395136/create-a-video-file-from-images-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It really a properly formatted answer and [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org) really does a good Job as stand alone application.and I have tried [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org) and it is really good in creating video from images, merging two or more videos. But here I am trying to directly convert images in video file and trying to ignore usage of any external application moreover limiting my application to stay in java only as external executable creates linking problem sometimes. Still your answer is helpful for other to create videos using ffmpeg.

Comment: @SkyWalker I have the same problem and I am trying to implement the suggested solution (Android Developers one). However, I can't seem to see where do you "feed" the algorithm with images in that function. So I have an array of bitmap images (which I will save each image locally on the device), then I would want to call your function. Where is the part where I tell the function "Here is the location of all of the images" .. "Create the video and put it in this location"?

Answer (score 4):

There is a utility in Java Media Framework which, It can create Video from List of Jpeg Images [Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jpegimagestomovie-176885.html)

Here is the source code:

**JpegImagesToMovie.java**

```
/*
 * @(#)JpegImagesToMovie.java   1.3 01/03/13
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 * Sun grants you ("Licensee") a non-exclusive, royalty free, license to use,
 * modify and redistribute this software in source and binary code form,
 * provided that i) this copyright notice and license appear on all copies of
 * the software; and ii) Licensee does not utilize the software in a manner
 * which is disparaging to Sun.
 * This software is provided "AS IS," without a warranty of any kind. ALL
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED CONDITIONS, REPRESENTATIONS AND WARRANTIES, INCLUDING ANY
 * IMPLIED WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE OR
 * NON-INFRINGEMENT, ARE HEREBY EXCLUDED. SUN AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES SUFFERED BY LICENSEE AS A RESULT OF USING, MODIFYING
 * OR DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE OR ITS DERIVATIVES. IN NO EVENT WILL SUN OR ITS
 * LICENSORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY LOST REVENUE, PROFIT OR DATA, OR FOR DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, SPECIAL, CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL OR PUNITIVE DAMAGES, HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND REGARDLESS OF THE THEORY OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF
 * OR INABILITY TO USE SOFTWARE, EVEN IF SUN HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
 *
 * This software is not designed or intended for use in on-line control of
 * aircraft, air traffic, aircraft navigation or aircraft communications; or in
 * the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any nuclear
 * facility. Licensee represents and warrants that it will not use or
 * redistribute the Software for such purposes.
 */

 package imagetovideo;

 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.util.Vector;
 import javax.media.Buffer;
 import javax.media.ConfigureCompleteEvent;
 import javax.media.ControllerEvent;
 import javax.media.ControllerListener;
 import javax.media.DataSink;
 import javax.media.EndOfMediaEvent; 
 import javax.media.Format;
 import javax.media.Manager; 
 import javax.media.MediaLocator;
 import javax.media.PrefetchCompleteEvent;
 import javax.media.Processor;
 import javax.media.RealizeCompleteEvent;
 import javax.media.ResourceUnavailableEvent;
 import javax.media.Time;
 import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
 import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkErrorEvent;
 import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkEvent;
 import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkListener;
 import javax.media.datasink.EndOfStreamEvent;
 import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
 import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
 import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;
 import javax.media.protocol.FileTypeDescriptor;
 import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferDataSource;
 import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferStream;

 /**
  * This program takes a list of JPEG image files and convert them into a
  * QuickTime movie.
 */
 public class JpegImagesToMovie implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener {

public boolean doIt(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector inFiles,
        MediaLocator outML) throws MalformedURLException {
    ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate,
            inFiles);

    Processor p;

    try {
        //System.err
        //      .println("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
        p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err
                .println("Yikes!  Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
        return false;
    }

    p.addControllerListener(this);

    // Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
    // some processing options on the processor.
    p.configure();
    if (!waitForState(p, p.Configured)) {
        System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
        return false;
    }

    // Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime.
    p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(
            FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

    // Query for the processor for supported formats.
    // Then set it on the processor.
    TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
    Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
    if (f == null || f.length <= 0) {
        System.err.println("The mux does not support the input format: "
                + tcs[0].getFormat());
        return false;
    }

    tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

    //System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

    // We are done with programming the processor. Let's just
    // realize it.
    p.realize();
    if (!waitForState(p, p.Realized)) {
        System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
        return false;
    }

    // Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
    DataSink dsink;
    if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null) {
        System.err
                .println("Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: "
                        + outML);
        return false;
    }

    dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
    fileDone = false;

    System.out.println("Generating the video : "+outML.getURL().toString());

    // OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
    try {
        p.start();
        dsink.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IO error during processing");
        return false;
    }

    // Wait for EndOfStream event.
    waitForFileDone();

    // Cleanup.
    try {
        dsink.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    p.removeControllerListener(this);

    System.out.println("Video creation completed!!!!!");
    return true;
}

/**
 * Create the DataSink.
 */
DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML) {

    DataSource ds;

    if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null) {
        System.err
                .println("Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
        return null;
    }

    DataSink dsink;

    try {
        //System.err.println("- create DataSink for: " + outML);
        dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
        dsink.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
        return null;
    }

    return dsink;
}

Object waitSync = new Object();
boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

/**
 * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state. Return
 * false if the transition failed.
 */
boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
    synchronized (waitSync) {
        try {
            while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
                waitSync.wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return stateTransitionOK;
}

/**
 * Controller Listener.
 */
public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {

    if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
            || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
            || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            stateTransitionOK = true;
            waitSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            stateTransitionOK = false;
            waitSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
        evt.getSourceController().stop();
        evt.getSourceController().close();
    }
}

Object waitFileSync = new Object();
boolean fileDone = false;
boolean fileSuccess = true;

/**
 * Block until file writing is done.
 */
boolean waitForFileDone() {
    synchronized (waitFileSync) {
        try {
            while (!fileDone)
                waitFileSync.wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return fileSuccess;
}

/**
 * Event handler for the file writer.
 */
public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

    if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            fileDone = true;
            waitFileSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            fileDone = true;
            fileSuccess = false;
            waitFileSync.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

/*public static void main(String args[]) {

    if (args.length == 0)
        prUsage();

    // Parse the arguments.
    int i = 0;
    int width = -1, height = -1, frameRate = 1;
    Vector inputFiles = new Vector();
    String outputURL = null;

    while (i < args.length) {

        if (args[i].equals("-w")) {
            i++;
            if (i >= args.length)
                prUsage();
            width = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
        } else if (args[i].equals("-h")) {
            i++;
            if (i >= args.length)
                prUsage();
            height = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
        } else if (args[i].equals("-f")) {
            i++;
            if (i >= args.length)
                prUsage();
            frameRate = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
        } else if (args[i].equals("-o")) {
            i++;
            if (i >= args.length)
                prUsage();
            outputURL = args[i];
        } else {
            inputFiles.addElement(args[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (outputURL == null || inputFiles.size() == 0)
        prUsage();

    // Check for output file extension.
    if (!outputURL.endsWith(".mov") && !outputURL.endsWith(".MOV")) {
        System.err
                .println("The output file extension should end with a .mov extension");
        prUsage();
    }

    if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
        System.err.println("Please specify the correct image size.");
        prUsage();
    }

    // Check the frame rate.
    if (frameRate < 1)
        frameRate = 1;

    // Generate the output media locators.
    MediaLocator oml;

    if ((oml = createMediaLocator(outputURL)) == null) {
        System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + outputURL);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();
    imageToMovie.doIt(width, height, frameRate, inputFiles, oml);

    System.exit(0);
}*/

static void prUsage() {
    System.err
            .println("Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie -w <width> -h <height> -f <frame rate> -o <output URL> <input JPEG file 1> <input JPEG file 2> ...");
    System.exit(-1);
}

/**
 * Create a media locator from the given string.
 */
static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(String url) {

    MediaLocator ml;

    if (url.indexOf(":") > 0 && (ml = new MediaLocator(url)) != null)
        return ml;

    if (url.startsWith(File.separator)) {
        if ((ml = new MediaLocator("file:" + url)) != null)
            return ml;
    } else {
        String file = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + File.separator + url;
        if ((ml = new MediaLocator(file)) != null)
            return ml;
    }

    return null;
}

// /////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Inner classes.
// /////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * A DataSource to read from a list of JPEG image files and turn that into a
 * stream of JMF buffers. The DataSource is not seekable or positionable.
 */
class ImageDataSource extends PullBufferDataSource {

    ImageSourceStream streams[];

    ImageDataSource(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector images) {
        streams = new ImageSourceStream[1];
        streams[0] = new ImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images);
    }

    public void setLocator(MediaLocator source) {
    }

    public MediaLocator getLocator() {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Content type is of RAW since we are sending buffers of video frames
     * without a container format.
     */
    public String getContentType() {
        return ContentDescriptor.RAW;
    }

    public void connect() {
    }

    public void disconnect() {
    }

    public void start() {
    }

    public void stop() {
    }

    /**
     * Return the ImageSourceStreams.
     */
    public PullBufferStream[] getStreams() {
        return streams;
    }

    /**
     * We could have derived the duration from the number of frames and
     * frame rate. But for the purpose of this program, it's not necessary.
     */
    public Time getDuration() {
        return DURATION_UNKNOWN;
    }

    public Object[] getControls() {
        return new Object[0];
    }

    public Object getControl(String type) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * The source stream to go along with ImageDataSource.
 */
class ImageSourceStream implements PullBufferStream {

    Vector images;
    int width, height;
    VideoFormat format;

    int nextImage = 0; // index of the next image to be read.
    boolean ended = false;

    public ImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
            Vector images) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.images = images;

        format = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG, new Dimension(width,
                height), Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray,
                (float) frameRate);
    }

    /**
     * We should never need to block assuming data are read from files.
     */
    public boolean willReadBlock() {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This is called from the Processor to read a frame worth of video
     * data.
     */
    public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

        // Check if we've finished all the frames.
        if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
            // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
            //System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
            buf.setEOM(true);
            buf.setOffset(0);
            buf.setLength(0);
            ended = true;
            return;
        }

        String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
        nextImage++;

        //System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

        // Open a random access file for the next image.
        RandomAccessFile raFile;
        raFile = new RandomAccessFile(imageFile, "r");

        byte data[] = null;

        // Check the input buffer type & size.

        if (buf.getData() instanceof byte[])
            data = (byte[]) buf.getData();

        // Check to see the given buffer is big enough for the frame.
        if (data == null || data.length < raFile.length()) {
            data = new byte[(int) raFile.length()];
            buf.setData(data);
        }

        // Read the entire JPEG image from the file.
        raFile.readFully(data, 0, (int) raFile.length());

        //System.err.println("    read " + raFile.length() + " bytes.");

        buf.setOffset(0);
        buf.setLength((int) raFile.length());
        buf.setFormat(format);
        buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | buf.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);

        // Close the random access file.
        raFile.close();
    }

    /**
     * Return the format of each video frame. That will be JPEG.
     */
    public Format getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor() {
        return new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW);
    }

    public long getContentLength() {
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean endOfStream() {
        return ended;
    }

    public Object[] getControls() {
        return new Object[0];
    }

    public Object getControl(String type) {
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Its doIt function can be called from another class having main function:

**CreatVideo.java**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
*/
package imagetovideo;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;


public class CreateVideo{

  public static final File dir = new File("D:\\imagesFolder\\");
  public static final String[] extensions = new String[]{"jpg", "png"};
  public static final FilenameFilter imageFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(final File dir, String name) {
        for (final String ext : extensions) {
            if (name.endsWith("." + ext)) {
                return (true);
            }
        }
        return (false);
    }
};

// Main function 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("D:\\a.mp4");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    Vector<String> imgLst = new Vector<>();
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        int counter = 1;
        for (final File f : dir.listFiles(imageFilter)) {               
            imgLst.add(f.getAbsolutePath());             

        }
    }
    makeVideo("file:\\" + file.getAbsolutePath(), imgLst);        
}

 public static void makeVideo(String fileName, Vector imgLst) throws MalformedURLException {
    JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();
    MediaLocator oml;
    if ((oml = imageToMovie.createMediaLocator(fileName)) == null) {
        System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + fileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    int interval = 40;
    imageToMovie.doIt(720, 360, (1000 / interval), imgLst, oml);
 }  
}
```

**Requirements**:

- Include [jmf-2.1.1e.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjmf211ejar.htm) in your Library Folder (using this library)

Comment: Hello, this looks like what I want to use. However, when I download the **requirement** zip library and extract it, it says it is invalid. Could you help me include the library to my android project? I am a noob with these stuff. Thanks